# Format output of formula field (which is used in charts etc.)

Tags: crystal-reports

The output of my formula field is typically formatted like this:

[Output of formula field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlsDH.png)

In my details I can switch this format to a number without any decimal points or thousand points:

[Format in details without points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm6DA.png)

The problem is, that this changed format isn´t displayed in the diagrams or cross tables later on:

[Format failure in diagrams or cross tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFl34.png)

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Formatting charts can be confusing because of how varied the layout can be for each different type of chart.  I find its is easier to format the display of a chart when you are previewing data on the chart because the layout for the chart in design view may not match what is output at runtime.  While previewing the report you should be able to click on any value or label on the chart to select the object.  You should see the four points around the object that allow you to resize the object once it is selected.  Then you can right click on the object and select "Format Selected Object" or "Format Axis Label" on the menu.  Then you should see a tab labeled "Number" where you will find options that allow you to control the formatting.  The options found here will vary a little depending upon the object selected on the chart.  If you need specific help with these options, it would be helpful if you could provide a screen shot of the window.